# Why can't I compile the iText source code?

Tags: itext

I get an error after running `mvn install -P all -e` to compile and install iText.
I've also done `mvn clean` on before hand. The error says:

```
testFlatteningGenerateAppearances2(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FlatteningTest):
    Path to GhostScript is not specified. Please use -DgsExec
```

Do I need to install Ghostscript?
I thought maven would take care of all dependencies.

```
C:\code4-itext\itext-code-6558-trunk\itext>mvn install -P all -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building iText, a Free Java-PDF library 5.5.4-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.1:create (default) @ itextpdf ---
[INFO] Checking for local modifications: skipped.
[INFO] Updating project files from SCM: skipped.
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive info"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\code4-itext\itext-code-6558-trunk\itext
[INFO] Storing buildNumber: null at timestamp: 1410923963268
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --non-interactive info"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\code4-itext\itext-code-6558-trunk\itext
[INFO] Storing buildScmBranch: UNKNOWN_BRANCH
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ itextpdf ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 24 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ itextpdf ---
[INFO] Compiling 601 source files to C:\code4-itext\itext-code-6558-trunk\itext\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.4:manifest (bundle-manifest) @ itextpdf ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ itextpdf ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 189 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ itextpdf ---
[INFO] Compiling 63 source files to C:\code4-itext\itext-code-6558-trunk\itext\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.9:test (default-test) @ itextpdf ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\code4-itext\itext-code-6558-trunk\itext\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.CMapAwareDocumentFontTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.25 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategyTest
Tests run: 21, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.094 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.VectorTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArrayTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.ChunkTest
Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.281 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.fonts.cmaps.CMapTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.cs.LabColorSpaceTest
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.031 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TextFieldTest
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.031 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.io.FileChannelRandomAccessSourceTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.062 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.io.GroupedRandomAccessSourceTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TaggedPdfCopyTest
Tests run: 30, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 24.726 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.MatrixTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.error_messages.ErrorMessageTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.MappedRandomAccessFileTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.html.parser.HtmlWorkerWhitSpaceTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.015 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.GlyphTextRenderListenerTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFieldsTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.047 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.io.ArrayRandomAccessSourceTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TestPdfCopyAndStamp
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRTokeniserTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ToUnicodeNonBreakableSpacesTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.io.PagedChannelRandomAccessSourceTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.015 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.io.GetBufferedRandomAccessSourceTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.fonts.cmaps.CMapParserExTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReaderSelectPagesTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.cs.DeviceNColorSpaceTest
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.table.RowspanTest
true
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.078 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.RemoteGifImageTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.983 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParserTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.signature.XmlDSigRsaTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.546 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.html.WebColorTest
Tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.015 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextRenderInfoTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.error_messages.MessageLocalizationTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.fonts.SymbolTest
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.error_messages.ErrorMessageExistenceTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.375 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.DocumentFontTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.015 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.html.parser.HtmlWorkerParagraphTest
Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.html.parser.HtmlWorkerLinkTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.UnbalancedOperatorsTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObjectTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.249 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FlatteningTest
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
Tests run: 9, Failures: 7, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.063 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running com.itextpdf.text.signature.XadesTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.234 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.signature.XmlDSigCertTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.093 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.MultiFilteredRenderListenerTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.468 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.TextMarginFinderTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReaderTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.MultithreadedTtfTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.234 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopyTest
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
[itext] INFO  Comparing by content..........OK
Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.406 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategyTest
Tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.signature.XmlDSigKSTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.109 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BookmarksTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractorEncodingsTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 2, Time elapsed: 0.187 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.io.WindowRandomAccessSourceTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.FilteredTextRenderListenerTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.015 sec
Running com.itextpdf.testutils.ClearOutTempFilesDuringTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.MetaDataTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.html.parser.HtmlXFAWorkerTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.TaggedPdfTest
Tests run: 25, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.342 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessorTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.015 sec
Running com.itextpdf.text.xml.xmp.XmpWriterTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.047 sec

Results :

Failed tests:   testFlatteningGenerateAppearances2(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FlatteningTest): Path to GhostScript is not specified. Please use -DgsExec=<p
ath_to_ghostscript> (e.g. -DgsExec="C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.14/bin/gswin32c.exe")
  testFlatteningGenerateAppearances1(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FlatteningTest): Path to GhostScript is not specified. Please use -DgsExec=<path_to_ghostsc
ript> (e.g. -DgsExec="C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.14/bin/gswin32c.exe")
  testFlattening(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FlatteningTest): Path to GhostScript is not specified. Please use -DgsExec=<path_to_ghostscript> (e.g. -DgsExec
="C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.14/bin/gswin32c.exe")
  testFlatteningGenerateAppearances4(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FlatteningTest): Path to GhostScript is not specified. Please use -DgsExec=<path_to_ghostsc
ript> (e.g. -DgsExec="C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.14/bin/gswin32c.exe")
  testFlatteningGenerateAppearances5(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FlatteningTest): Path to GhostScript is not specified. Please use -DgsExec=<path_to_ghostsc
ript> (e.g. -DgsExec="C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.14/bin/gswin32c.exe")
  testFlatteningGenerateAppearances6(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FlatteningTest): Path to GhostScript is not specified. Please use -DgsExec=<path_to_ghostsc
ript> (e.g. -DgsExec="C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.14/bin/gswin32c.exe")
  testFlatteningGenerateAppearances3(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.FlatteningTest): Path to GhostScript is not specified. Please use -DgsExec=<path_to_ghostsc
ript> (e.g. -DgsExec="C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.14/bin/gswin32c.exe")

Tests run: 246, Failures: 7, Errors: 0, Skipped: 4

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 45.209 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-16T20:20:07-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/552M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.9:test (default-test) on project itextpdf: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\code4-itext\itext-code-6558-trunk\itext\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.9:test (default-test)
on project itextpdf: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\code4-itext\itext-code-6558-trunk\itext\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\code4-itext\itext-code-6558-trunk\itext\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:87)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.writeSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:631)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:605)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:136)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:97)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
C:\code4-itext\itext-code-6558-trunk\itext>
```

Comment: It's but a test. Simply build with tests disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the parameter `maven.test.skip=true` or `skipTests=true` in the command line. The tests create plenty of PDF files (new documents) that need to be compared with reference PDF files (existing documents stored with the tests). Ghostscript is used to create images of those PDF files. These images are compared on a pixel basis to check if the new files have the same appearance of the reference files.

If you want to build iText *with* the tests, you need Ghostscript.
If you want to build iText merely to get a jar, you can skip the tests and you don't need Ghostscript.